# Running code on a daily basis at set time on Citrix?

Tags: python, citrix

I created some Python script that I want to be run every morning at a set time.  I run the code in a virtual workspace environment, known as Citrix.  Initially, I was worried that my code would not run at a set time because my laptop would be closed, and it would have no way of signing me in and running the code at a set time.

However, since I am running it in Citrix, would this be possible?  I disconnect from Citrix at the end of the day, but never shut down windows in the Citrix environment, so it should still be running 24/7, and thus can run my code at a set time every morning, correct? Even when I am not accessing my Citrix on my laptop at that time?

If not, what can I add to my code to get around this issue so it can be running behind the scenes at a set time, even while my laptop is closed/off?

Comment: Your server is still running.  You should be able to use the Windows "Scheduled Task" facility to run something at a fixed time every day.

Comment: _even while my laptop is closed/off_ If your laptop is actually **powered off**, then I don't think it's going to be running anything...

Comment: @JohnGordon The program will run on the Citrix server, not the laptop.

Comment: If Citrix is running on a server, it should process scheduled jobs independent of whether the client application is connected.